# Что нужно дописать в адресной строке браузера, чтобы при открытии страница отматывалась на нужное слово

Tags: html, браузер, href, гиперссылка

Сейчас я делаю это в 3 движения:

1. Нажимаю на закладку из избранного
2. CTRL+F и поиск нужного слова
3. Переход на нужное место на странице

Можно ли что-то дописать в текст ссылки, чтобы исключить этапы 2 и 3 и при нажатии на ссылку всё сразу перемещалось на место с нужным словом.

Я на разработчик, а пользователь. Доступа к изменению кода нет. Слово - на русском языке.

Спасибо.

Comment: Такой возможности нет и она в теории сложна в реализации. Например, на странице есть 100 слов, какое именно вы "сохранили"? Даже если позицию слова сохранять, есть вероятность, что позиция слова может поменяться и тогда вам выдаст неверный результат при переходе на закладку.

Comment: О каком браузере идет речь?

Comment: Это Google Chrome

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome позволяет копировать ссылку на выбранный текст.

Для этого нужно:

1. выделить текст
2. открыть контекстное меню
3. выбрать пункт - копировать ссылку на текст

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Это то что надо